# MySQL - using stored procedure with nested statements

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, parameters, nested

Newbie to MySQL here - I'm having trouble feeding parameters into nested statements in a stored procedure.

The following 3 statements work perfectly when executed sequentially.

```
insert into rental(movie_id, membership_id, format, no_nights) 
values (3014, 10004, "dvd", 2);

update rental  
inner join movie_format on rental.movie_id = movie_format.movie_id  
set rental_cost = daily_rental_cost * no_nights  
where rental.movie_id = 3014 and rental.format = "dvd" and membership_id = 10004;

update rental  
set rental_cost_due = rental_cost  
where rental.movie_id = 3014 and rental.format = "dvd" and membership_id = 10004;
```

However, when I try and use a stored procedure with one set of parameters the where clauses give error messages such as ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'movie_id_in' in 'where clause'

```
delimiter //  
create procedure usp_rent_movie   
        (IN movie_id_in int, membership_id_in int, format_in varchar(15), no_nights_in int)  

    insert into rental(movie_id, membership_id, format, no_nights) 
    values (movie_id_in, membership_id_in, format_in, no_nights_in);  

    update rental  
    inner join movie_format on rental.movie_id = movie_format.movie_id  
    set rental_cost = daily_rental_cost * no_nights   
    where rental.movie_id = movie_id_in and rental.format = format_in and membership_id = membership_id_in;  

    update rental   
    set rental_cost_due = rental_cost  
    where rental.movie_id = movie_id_in and rental.format = format_in and membership_id = membership_id_in;   
end//   
delimiter ;
```

Apologies if this is a simple error, I've been at this for hours!

Comment: Which query is getting the error?

Comment: I suspect there's a typo somewhere, and you didn't copy it here.

Comment: If I add in actual values for the two update tables they work perfectly, they don't seem to be reading in the parameters.  If I just put in values for movie_id for example the where statement then gives me an error for the next parameter, format, and so on.

Comment: you're missing the `begin` statement

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `BEGIN` and `END` if you have multiple statements in your procedure body.

```
delimiter //  
create procedure usp_rent_movie   
        (IN movie_id_in int, membership_id_in int, format_in varchar(15), no_nights_in int)  
BEGIN
    insert into rental(movie_id, membership_id, format, no_nights) 
    values (movie_id_in, membership_id_in, format_in, no_nights_in);  

    update rental  
    inner join movie_format on rental.movie_id = movie_format.movie_id  
    set rental_cost = daily_rental_cost * no_nights   
    where rental.movie_id = movie_id_in and rental.format = format_in and membership_id = membership_id_in;  

    update rental   
    set rental_cost_due = rental_cost  
    where rental.movie_id = movie_id_in and rental.format = format_in and membership_id = membership_id_in; 
end//   
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Yeah, I got rid of the second `END`. I'm not sure why that worked at all for you, since it didn't match any `BEGIN`.